# How to force a java bean to be updated after using back button?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, javabeans

Suppose I have a jsp page called index1.jsp. On this page I have a checkbox, 
as follows.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="index2.jsp">
<input type="checkbox" name="check">
```

On my server I have a java bean say mybean that has setCheck and getCheck 
functions.

I also have the following at the end.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

I check the check box, click on submit button, I go to the next page, 
 and the function setCheck of mybean is called.

then I click **the back button** of my browser, go back to index1.jsp
 uncheck the checkbox, and click submit button.

I again go to index2.jsp, but this time, mybean is not updated, setCheck is not called, when I check the value, the "check" variable of mybean is still "on", even though I just turned it off.

Can anyone tell me how I can go back to the jsp page, uncheck the check button and have it reflected in my bean, that has a member variable of the same name as the check box name in my jsp ?

Answer (score 0):

when you press "Back button" on the browser, it go back to cached version of the previous JSP (responsed).

Try this:

Adding this code to your jsp will cause most browsers to not cache the response:

```
<%
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); // HTTP 1.1
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
%>
```